# Why doesn't Visual Studio Emulator for Android launch anymore?

Tags: visual-studio, android-emulator, visual-studio-2015

I'm using Visual Studio 2015 Enterprise with the new Android Emulator. It worked pretty well for a while but suddenly it stopped working.

The output in VS shows always this:

```
1>Starting emulator: VS Emulator 5.1" Lollipop (5.1.1) XXHDPI Phone
1>Validating emulator arguments...
1>Determining if emulator is already running...
1>Preparing virtual machine...
1>Launching emulator...
```

The emulator window appears but it stucks on the black "Loading..." screen. I see in the taskmanager that `xde.exe` is consuming between 25% and 32% of CPU power. There are no entries in the Windows eventlog telling anything about `xde` or Hyper-V. 
I've already deleted all virtual computers in the Hyper-V-Manager as suggested by Microsoft on the [Troubleshooting the Visual Studio Emulator for Android](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt228282.aspx#NoStart) page.

Has anyone an idea how to get the emulator running again?

Comment: What version of Windows are you running? If Windows 10, what build? The newest flight seems to have broken Hyper-V.

Comment: The `ver` command gives me this result: `Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.10240]`. 
Is it a broken version?

Comment: Please follow up if you figure this out, I have the exact same problem.

Comment: I found out if I disable the vswitch for my primary network connection the emulator will then launch. I can then re-enable my network

Comment: @JasonSmith This doesn't solve my problem. I deleted all switches: Same result. I deleted only network related switches: Same result. I deleted the switches one by one: Same result :-(

Comment: No no, not the switches, literally disable the network interfaces except the windows phone vswitch. Then once the emulator is booted, turn it back on. If you delete them Xde will recreate them, you want them created but disabled in the control panel. The only thing to leave enabled is the windows phone one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you face the same problem then you can try to solve it by these steps:

**1. Delete all virtual switches**

Try it the way John Kemnetz told in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32722602/2023316):

> Go to Hyper-V Manager, and delete all virtual switches via the Virtual
>   Switch Manager 2) In Hyper-V Manager, delete all VMs. 3) Restart the
>   computer. 4) Start an emulator.

**2. Disable network interfaces**

If this doesn't work then try to do it the way Jason Smith described in a comment:

> disable the network interfaces except the windows phone vswitch. Then
>   once the emulator is booted, turn it back on. If you delete them Xde
>   will recreate them, you want them created but disabled in the control
>   panel. The only thing to leave enabled is the windows phone one.

In case this doesn't work neither (which was my case) then

**3. Reinstall Visual Studio 2015 Emulator for Android**

Uninstall the emulator, reboot the PC and install it again. This worked for me. But I suggest to try the other two options first as the third option can be really time consuming.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

1. Go to Hyper-V Manager, and delete all virtual switches via the Virtual Switch Manager
2. In Hyper-V Manager, delete all VMs.
3. Restart the computer.
4. Start an emulator.

Windows 10 updates for some computers are causing problems with virtual switches and they need to be recreated by the emulator from scratch.

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately that changed nothing. The emulator still doesn't load. The only change I see is a blurry second monitor as soon as I turn on UI element scaling on my first high DPI monitor. That worked before I deleted the switches. During the first attempt of deleting the switches the computer froze and I had to turn it off hardly. That's really strange.